# Apply PhysicsWorld to every object in GenericPool - Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I have `GenericPool` class (*creates required number of Sprites then I reuse these sprites again and again*) and `PhysicsWorld` class (*used to apply physics to Sprites like gravity friction etc*).

The `PhysicsWorld` class works fine with single Sprite, and `GenericPool` works fine without applying `physicsWorld` to its Sprites. The problem occurs when I want to apply `PhysicsWorld` to all objects of `GenericPool` sprites.

Please give me direction on how should I apply `PhysicsWorld` to all objects in genericpool..

```
public class BubblePool<Sprite>{

TextureRegion bubbleTexture

BubblePool(TextureRegion mTextureRegion)

this.bubbleTexture=mTextureRegion;

}

protected onAllocatePoolItem(){

return new Sprite(0,0,bubbleTexture,....);


}
```

an other class of PhysicsWorld

```
public class BubblePhysics{

//all method including FixtueDef and //body then PhysicsConnector etc
}
```

BubblePhysics class is separate class working fine with one sprite.. but now i want to connect this class to BubblePool.. in BubblePool new sprite is created in onAllocatePoolItem() method i want that when sprite is created how should i use physicsworld..

Comment: What kind of problem do you have there? What did you try? Could you post your code?

Comment: I just want right direction that how should i apply PhysicsWorld to all object in GenericPool.. suppose i have GenericPool class named BubblePool and i have 10 bubbles stored in pool i reuse these bubbles again and again.. now i want to apply some gravity to all of these 10 bubbles...how should i do this.. give me right direction plz...

Comment: Same as you do that for one sprite. Register physics connector to the object in pool. It is not easy to help if we can't see what you already tried and how your code looks like. You said that problem occurs - what kind of problem?

Comment: ok thanksss a lot for help.. i will try this... :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem(PhysicsWorld physicsWorld){

Sprite sprite = new Sprite(0,0,bubbleTexture,....);
final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);
PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(physicsWorld, sprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);
physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sprite, body, true, true));

return sprite;
}
```

I would start from here. Let me know if it works.

Comment: onAllocatePoolItem(){} is super class method it gives error when i add argument PhysicsWorld to it.. like this onAllocatePoolItem(PhysicsWorld physicsWorld){}......    but i have got an idea how to do that...thanks for help...

Comment: Ah, I did not use this for a while... you may use physicsWorld as static and will not have to pass it as parameter:)